# liquibase mark changeset applied

Tags: maven, liquibase

How is it possible to mark specific changeset as applied in liquibase maven plugin? There's nothing about that in documentation, the command **markNextChangeSetRan** seems to do nothing.

Comment: Is your problem specific to the Maven plugin, or is this about liquibase in general?  If the former, an example of how you would do what you want from the CLI would be helpful for clarification.

Comment: @jordan002 it is related to maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-maven-plugin) in the current master branch (which is currently 3.0.0-beta2-SNAPSHOT) it seems that there simply is no implementation of the `markNextChangeSetRan` command.

So I guess, it's simply not there.

You could add a ticket to request this in the [liquibase JIRA](https://liquibase.jira.com) but there seems to be no project for the maven plugin (don't know though if the maven plugin for liquibase is tracked elsewhere).

Sorry to have no better answer. I just checked out the complete liquibase code from [github](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase) myself to implement a missing feature and so I thought I just quickly check this.

Answer (score 4):

There is a "hacky" solution for this problem:

1. Delete all the children of the problematic `changeSet` XML element. Remember to leave the `changeSet` with its id and author parameters in the liquibase XML file.
2. Run `mvn liquibase:update`

   - It should say it ran the required specific `changeSet`.
3. Revert the XML file that you modified.
4. Run `mvn liquibase:update` again

   - You will get `Validation Failed: 1 change sets check sum` with the new sum. Copy that new check sum from the error.
5. Paste the check sum manually into the right record in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table of the target database.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `mvn liquibase:changelogSyncSQL` to generate a set of SQL statements that will mark your changesets as applied.

It will put the queries in `target/liquibase/migrate.sql`. You can then manually execute these SQL statements in your DB.

https://b-gyula.github.io/liquibase-doc/documentation/existing_project